# Detect Differences between Safari Webview and Safari on iOS using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What are the differences in terms of features or apis of Safari webview and regular safari on iOS? Is there a way to detect if a website is open in Safari webview like say from Twitter?

Currently I have pwa enabled in my app, but for iOS, the user has to add the app to their homescreen using the share button. Now, when the link is opened from twitter app, twitter renders the website in Safari webview. I'm trying to detect if website is opened in safari webview so I can show a message to user on how to add the app to their homescreen due to the safari webview limitations where Add to home is not available in the share sheet.

[image]

Comment: The first question is "why?". If there are specific APIs you need for your page to work, you generally test for those without caring about which browser you're in in the slightest, and shimming any API that doesn't appear to be natively supported (although these days, most of the time, most APIs are - using https://caniuse.com is always a good idea)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Currently I have pwa enabled in my app, but for iOS, the user has to add the app to their homescreen using the share button. Now, when the link is opened from twitter app, twitter renders the website in Safari webview. I'm trying to detect if website is opened in safari webview so I can show a message to user on how to add the app to their homescreen due to the safari webview limitations where Add to home is not available in the share sheet.

Comment: That is important information relevant to your question, so: remember to [put those details in your post](/help/how-to-ask) =)